# PowerShell Conditional Efficiency: -match vs. -like

Tags: regex, performance, powershell

I have a simple Powershell script that collects Exchange message tracking results using a few filters and then returns items with '*SPAM*' in the subject.  To do so, I take an array of Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.MessageTrackingEvent objects and pipe it to a 'where' that checks the MessageSubject property of each entry.

I found that when I use the following for comparing the MessageSubject property, the code takes an extremely long time (hours) to complete for ~70,000 records:

($_.messagesubject -like '`*SPAM`*')

However when I use the following, the completion time is in seconds:

($_.messagesubject -match [regex]'^\*SPAM\*.*$')

I'm getting in over my head trying to determine the specific reasons the former takes so much longer to process.  Don't both methods need to loop over the same number of objects?  Is the difference in character-by-character comparisons (for -like) vs. a compiled regex? (for -match)

Comment: First of all, your regex is not equivalent to wildcard. `^\*` means an asterisk at the beginning of a line. The equivalent regex pattern would be just 'SPAM'.

Comment: I should have been more clear: the subject of the email would always begin with \*SPAM\*.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure that switching operators is the only thing that changes between versions? According to the following tests, performance of operators is not an issue. Moreover, the regex cast is the longest one. I also believe that the like pattern you use is wrong, you need to escape the asterisks as they are special wildcard characters (see $sb4).

```
PS> $msg = "just a sample spam message for testing"

PS> $sb1 = { 1..70000 | foreach {$msg -match [regex]'^\*SPAM\*.*$' } }
PS> $sb2 = { 1..70000 | foreach {$msg -match 'spam'} }
PS> $sb3 = { 1..70000 | foreach {$msg -like "*spam*" } }
PS> $sb4 = { 1..70000 | foreach {$msg -like "`*spam`*" } }    

PS> (measure-command $sb1).TotalSeconds
8.1869412

PS> (measure-command $sb2).TotalSeconds
6.7244995

PS> (measure-command $sb3).TotalSeconds
7.9287195

PS> (measure-command $sb4).TotalSeconds
6.9678701
```

Comment: That is an error in my original post: the wildcard characters were escaped.  I am going to try the two iterations using measure-command in my setup.

Comment: I found similar results as you.  What was actually affecting the run time of my script was another command that selected unique objects from a list.  Thanks for the response, though.